# Mix of numerical and categorical features - to scale or not to scale?

Tags: classification, random-forest, linear-model, scikit-learn, feature-scaling

I have the means of my features like this of an employee dataset:

```
        avg_score       salary      tenure      bonus     avg_hrs_month                                                
mean    0.651826        2.017505    6.556184    0.212055    184.661571
```

It is obvious to scale 'avg_hrs-month'. however, the bonus feature is binomial (0 or 1), and salary has been autoencoded as (1,2,3), and tenure is a sequence of numbers (3,4, 5,6,7,8,9,10).

Is it advisable to apply autoscaling to all of them?

- for a linear classification model such as sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression, or sklearn.svm.LinearSVC?¶
- for a decision tree-based model such as ensemble.RandomForestClassifier([...])?

It is a a binary classification problem (yes or no). thank you very much.

Comment: Is one of these variables the class variable you want to predict? As far as I can see, all these methods are invariant to scaling, so my first guess is it won't make a difference. I don't use sklearn though, so I'm just guessing what the methods are.

Comment: In LPM or in binary choice models, like logit/probit etc....we can use both qualitative and quantitative variables as regressors. If you are looking for classification, probably you are think of Discriminant model or Principle Component Analysis or Factor models.

Comment: I think the goals should come first in your question. What appears obvious for these goals to you is far from obvious in general.

Comment: Yes, the target variable is binary (2 classes, 0 or 1).